# Google Sheets + Apps Script + Webapps: Pull and edit an existing row data and update row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hi I'm trying to pull the data from a google sheet from the row that matches the selected ID number to edit the data then click on the update button so the matching row gets updated in google sheet here's a link to my google sheet. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eaEfRtjMz7kyQfyXZHLuBhSz91SiUJzq1J2QJexJxy4/edit?ts=5fc42833#gid=0

**here's my gs code**

```
  function doGet(request) {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
 
}

/* @Include JavaScript and CSS Files */
function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
/* @Process Form */



function getCustDetail(search) {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var idvCustData = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow(),8).getValues();
  var custIdList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var custDateList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[2]; });
  var custclientList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[3]; });
  var custlocationList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[4]; });
  var custother1List = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[5]; });
  var custother2List = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[6]; });
 
  
  
  var searchPostion = custIdList.indexOf(search);
  var custDetail = {};
  custDetail.custId = custIdList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custDate = custDateList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custclient = custclientList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custlocation = custlocationList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custother1 = custother1List[searchPostion];
  custDetail.custother2 = custother2List[searchPostion];

  Logger.log(searchPostion);
  Logger.log(custDetail);
  Logger.log(search);
  
  if (searchPostion > -1){
  
  return  custDetail;
   
  } else {
    return '-';
 }
}
```

**here's my JS code**

```
<script>
  // Prevent forms from submitting.
  function preventFormSubmit() {
    var forms = document.querySelectorAll('form');
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
      forms[i].addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      
      });
    }
  }
  window.addEventListener('load', preventFormSubmit);  
  
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    
  
 }           

//Retrieve Customer
function getCustomer() {
  
  var searchId = document.getElementById("Id").value;
  
 if (searchId != ""){
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(custDetail).getCustDetail(searchId);
  } 
  
}

//Success Handler
function custDetail(){

  document.getElementById("Id").innerHTML = cust.Id;
  document.getElementById("Date").innerHTML = cust.Date;
  document.getElementById("client").innerHTML = cust.client;
  document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = cust.location;
  document.getElementById("other1").innerHTML = cust.other1;
  document.getElementById("other2").innerHTML = cust.other2;

  M.updateTextFields();
  
}
</script>
```

**Here's my HTML code**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
    
    <?!= include('JavaScript'); ?>
    <?!= include('CSS'); ?>
    
    <!-- Select2 CDN -->
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.1.0-beta.1/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
        
        
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
   
   
   
   
     <!-- CSS only -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href= "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity= "sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z"
        crossorigin="anonymous"> 
  
    <!-- JS, Popper.js, jquery and jQuery autocomplete -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity= "sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" 
        crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script> 
    <script src= "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity= "sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script> 
    <script src= "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity= "sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
        crossorigin="anonymous"> 
    </script>   

    </head>
   
      <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="handleFormSubmit(this)">
                      <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center">Ticket Form</p>
                      
                      
           <div class="form-row">
           
           
           
           

              
               <div class="form-group col-md-2">
               <label for="Id">ID</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Id" name ="Id">
              </div>
              
             
              
              <div class="form-group col-md-2">
               <label for="Date">Ticket Date</label>
               <input type="date" class="form-control" id="Date" name ="Date">
              </div>
              
               <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                 <label for="client">Client</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="client" name="client" >
               </div>
                           
               <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                 <label for="location">Location</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="location" name="location" >
               </div>
             </div>
   
          <div class="form-row">
             
             <div class="form-group col-md-2">
               <label for="other1">Other1</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="other1" name ="other1">
              </div>
              
              <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                 <label for="other2">Other2</label>
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="other2" name="other2" >
               </div>
                
            </div>
               <hr>
                 <br>
                         
                   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block col-md-4 ">Update</button>
                        
             </form>

                     <br>
                    <div id="output"></div>
                  </div>
                 </div>      
                </div>
               </body>
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the current issue of your script?

Comment: yes i cant get the data to show on the webapp

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that when I saw the scripts of your shared Spreadsheet, it seems that those are different from your question. Which scripts are the latest?

Comment: the one from the shared sheet is the latest I copied it from that sheet not sure why it would be different but I'm on the shared sheet. thanks

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Modification points:

- At Google Apps Script side:

  - When I saw the scripts in your shared Spreadsheet, it seems that the function `getCustDetail` doesn't return the values. But, your script in your question returns `custDetail`.
  - At `getCustDetail`, you have already set the value of `search`. So in this case, the value is always used. Please be careful this.
  - When the value is put to the input with `type="date"`, the value is required to be `yyyy-MM-dd`.
  - Even when `custDetail` is returned, `custDetail()` at Javascript side doesn't use the argument.
  - Even when `custDetail` uses the argument from Google Apps Script side, the keys returned from Google Apps Script are different from them at Javascript side.
- At Javascript side:

  - In your shared Spreadsheet, `var data = google.script.run.getCustDetail();` is used. But in the current stage, `google.script.run` returns no values. Please be careful this.
  - When you want to set the value to the text input, please use `value` instead of `innerHTML`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

### Modified script:

#### Google Apps Script side:

Please modify `getCustDetail` as follows.

```
function getCustDetail(search) {
  search = Number(search);
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var idvCustData = ws.getRange(2,1,ws.getLastRow(),8).getValues();
  var custIdList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[0]; });
  var custDateList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[2]; });
  var custclientList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[3]; });
  var custlocationList = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[4]; });
  var custother1List = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[5]; });
  var custother2List = idvCustData.map(function(r){ return r[6]; });
  var searchPostion = custIdList.indexOf(search);
  var custDetail = {};
  custDetail.Id = custIdList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.Date = custDateList[searchPostion] && Utilities.formatDate(custDateList[searchPostion], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy-MM-dd");
  custDetail.client = custclientList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.location = custlocationList[searchPostion];
  custDetail.other1 = custother1List[searchPostion];
  custDetail.other2 = custother2List[searchPostion];
  if (searchPostion > -1){
    return  custDetail;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

- In this case, it supposes that IDs of the column "A" in Spreadsheet are always the number. Please be careful this.

#### Javascript side:

Please modify `custDetail` as follows.

```
function custDetail(cust){
  if (cust) {
    document.getElementById("Id").value = cust.Id;
    document.getElementById("Date").value = cust.Date;
    document.getElementById("client").value = cust.client;
    document.getElementById("location").value = cust.location;
    document.getElementById("other1").value = cust.other1;
    document.getElementById("other2").value = cust.other2;
    M.updateTextFields();
  }
}
```

### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**

Comment: thanks Tanaike those modification work good. Another question if you could help me out is how do I get it to update the row once I have made the change and I press the update button thanks again

Comment: @Yvan L Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your "Another question", I would like to check it when I found your new question. Thank you, too.